# Is there any walkthrough for enabling the password recovery feature for MVC 5 ASP.Net Web app using visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been through many tutorials but none of them were just fine for a MVC newbie like me. I find many articles on ASP.Net websites but there were no one on MVC5. I am wondering why this feature is just not enabled as MVC web apps provide Membership?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity

Comment: Thanks @BrendanGreen. This helped me out to run this feature. By the way i can't vote up for insufficient reputation :)